# Azure Change Feed and Querying based on Partition

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

When we fetch data from Document Db in the change feed, we only want it per partition and have tried adding PatitionKey to the code.

```
do
        {
            FeedResponse<PartitionKeyRange> pkRangesResponse = await client.ReadPartitionKeyRangeFeedAsync(
                collectionUri,
                new FeedOptions
                {
                    RequestContinuation = pkRangesResponseContinuation,
                    PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("KEY"),
                });

            partitionKeyRanges.AddRange(pkRangesResponse);
            pkRangesResponseContinuation = pkRangesResponse.ResponseContinuation;
        }
        while (pkRangesResponseContinuation != null);
```

It returns single range and when we go perform the second query

```
IDocumentQuery<Document> query = client.CreateDocumentChangeFeedQuery(
                collectionUri,
                new ChangeFeedOptions
                {
                    PartitionKeyRangeId = pkRange.Id,
                    StartFromBeginning = true,
                    RequestContinuation = continuation,
                    MaxItemCount = -1,
                });
```

It returns all the results from all partitions. Is there a way to restrict the results from single partition only?

Comment: According to this [artilce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed#a-idrest-apisaworking-with-the-rest-api-and-sdk), the CreateDocumentChangeFeedQuery method will get the result from a partition range, we couldn't just restrict the results from single partition.

Comment: So from that recommendation, change feed can only be supported through intermediary server and not directly by clients? As clients may not have access to other partition data?

Comment: In my opinion, intermediary server is also a client. The change feed is used to  rack changes made to Azure Cosmos DB data. The azure documentdb server just support the partition range track. So we could only use the  partition range.

Answer (score 1):

Changefeed works at a PartitionKey Range level.

**What are partition key ranges?**

Document Db currently has 10 GB Physical partitions.
The partition key that you specify is the Logical Partition Key.
Document Db internally maps this logical partition key to a Physical Partition using a hash.
So its possible that a bunch of logical partitions are sharing the same physical partition.
So a physical partition is assigned for a range of these hashes.

The minimum grain that is allowed to read from changefeed would be Partition key ranges.
So for the you would have to query the partition key range id for the partition that you are interested in. Then query the Changefeed for that range id and filter out the data that is not associated to the partition id.

**Note**: Document db transparently creates new physical partitions if a particular partition gets full. So the partition key range id for a given logical partition could change over time.

This link explains this in good detail:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data#partitioning-in-azure-cosmos-db